# Getter and @Nonnull

Tags: java, null, annotations, non-nullable

I get a warning from eclipse and I know I can remove it with suppress warning but I'd prefer to understand what makes it thing it could be null.

package-info.java

```
@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
package test;

import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
```

test.java

```
package test;


public class Test {
    public static void main( final String[ ] args ) {
        System.out.println( new Test( "a" ).getS( ) );
    }

    private final String s;

    public Test( final String s ) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public String getS( ) {
        return this.s;//Null type safety: The expression of type String needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@Nonnull String'
    }
}
```

I don't get why I get this warning...

PS:

`public Test( @Nonnull final String s ) {` -> The nullness annotation is redundant with a default that applies to this location

`@Nonnull private final String s;` -> nothing changes

Comment: Javadocs are supposed to *improve* comprehension :( Also, be wary of fluent return values for setters--they are *not* "legal" JavaBean setters, and various tools will either complain about it, or not even see them. IMO it's better to keep the JavaBean and fluent methods separate.

Comment: How could I improve comprehension on a code that simple... I simply described the methods because you can't see the content from the javadoc page.

Comment: By removing the redundant Javadocs.

Comment: About the JavaBean things, that's not what I'm aiming for. I'm just learning Java to know what it's like but it really isn't the type of language I like. E.g. having to use a visitor pattern because you can't assume your object is an instance of whatever you checked it was an instance of with the instanceof operator...

Comment: You mean removing the descriptions of what is returned when I already use @return?

Comment: Getters and setters don't require documentation unless they do something beyond get and set. Over-marking-up makes them illegible in anything other than processed form. Stating that a property named `value` is "The value" doesn't provide any useful information; that's self-evident.

Comment: Alright. I removed these comments. Should I update my question with the "new" code?

Comment: Doesn't matter, but *I* would--the comments aren't relevant to the question and will just slow people down. But that's only my opinion.

Comment: Do you have the @ParametersAreNonnullByDefault notation in the test package as well?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I had the problem on the xjnode package and then I edited to remove anything that had nothing to do with the problem.
And I forgot to update the package's name.
But Obviously, I wouldn't get the warnings saying it's redundant when I add @Nonnull if it weren't there.
Thanks for pointing that out anyway.

Comment: Eclipse 4.3 added annotation-based null analysis for fields (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331649)

Comment: @Gilead But it's still a pile of fail for constants and enums.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the @Nonnull annotation has no effects on fields. It is only supported for:

- Method parameters
- Method return values
- Local variables (within a code block)

[See eclipse Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-using_null_annotations.htm)

So quite obviously - as Nonnull is not checked on fields - the compiler doesn't know that Test.s is Nonnull and complains about it.

The obvious solution would indeed be to add a @SuppressWarnings("null") on the field access (or on the method, if it's a simple getter):

```
public String getS() {
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Nonnull String s = this.s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I don't use Eclipse's annotations... I use the ones from javax. I told so to eclipse but you're telling me it simply assumes I changed the name. Is there a way to tell it doesn't behave exactly the same way?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I'm getting your first comment... What annotations you're using is irrelevant (just tell Eclipse the full class names). You could also use your own so you don't have to import an external library.

Comment: See [Eclipse bug #331649 (consider null annotations for fields)](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331649) to find out about the current status of null annotation support for fields.