# Guava Optional and @NonNull annotation

Tags: java, guava, option-type, non-nullable, jsr305

I'm trying different ways of getting rid of NPEs in my code. I use nullness analysis in Eclipse and I'm quite fond of @NonNullByDefault. But today I run into a problem with guava's Optional:

```
private static Optional<Foo> bar() {
  Foo foobar = new Foo();
  return Optional.of(foobar);
}
```

I get following comment on the return line:

```
Null type safety: The expression of type 'Optional<Foo>' needs unchecked conversion to conform to   '@NonNull Optional<Foo>'
```

I tried using JSR305 annotations to no avail. Is there a way to make it work (use both Optional and @NonNull annotations)?

Comment: Couldn't find nothing helpful. Most articles describe using annotations OR using Optional - nothing on using both. I found a discussion on guava forum about using JSR305 but as I said - changing to JSR305 didn't help

Comment: It sounds like this can't work if Eclipse won't let you designate outside methods as returning @NonNull?

Comment: What's `Foo` and why are you trying to put a string into it?

Comment: Sorry - my mistake. I edited the post. The point is, that the null analysis assumes that Optional.of() may return null and so it gives a warning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241983/ & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462257/

Answer (score 0):

The full solution to this question requires null annotations in the Optional API. In particular of() should be declared to return @NonNull.

Until the library authors annotate their API, you will need external annotations, support for which is being developed for Eclipse Mars.
See https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Null_Analysis/External_Annotations

OTOH, I'm curious, why indeed you want both concepts for NPE avoidance combined in one project.

Answer (score 0):

Guava code treats non-null as the default, but it doesn't use Eclipse's `@NonNullByDefault` annotation, since it's non-standard. Instead it uses the standard `@Nullable` annotation to indicate parameters and return types that *can* be `null`.

The awesome [Error Prone](http://errorprone.info/) project provides null-safety checks that are compatible with this standard approach - I'd suggest using it rather than your IDE's custom checks.